# Pull request de branch desatualizada no Git

Tags: git, github, merge

Criei um *branch* de um repositório no *GitHub*. Trabalhei nesse *branch* criando os seus próprios *commits*. O *branch* está no repositório remoto.

Entretanto foram evoluindo o *master*, desenvolvendo código no *master*.

Em princípio os desenvolvimentos do *master* e do *branch* são em ficheiros diferentes.

Queria fazer um pull request, para juntar o código do branch no master. Qual é o melhor caminho, de modo a manter todos os ficheiros actualizados?

Exemplo de esquema de *commits*:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G -> master
   \     /
    A-B-C -> mobile
```

Comment: Tem certeza que não é `pull request` o que você quer? Eu trabalho usando o gitflow, somos quase 10 desenvolvedores mexendo em códigos e códigos, muitas vezes mexendo nos mesmos arquivos. Normalmente em funções diferentes, mas o mesmo arquivo mesmo assim. Como cada _branch_ tem um propósito de evolução distinto e o destino final são `master`, `develop` ou a `rc` sendo estabilizada no momento, não nos preocupamos muito em manter cada um dos 20 ou 30 _branches_ em sincronismo

Comment: Faça um pull de sua branch com a master, resolva os possíveis conflitos e depois faça um pull request para a master. Isso atualizará a sua branch e a master para o mesmo código.

Answer (score 1):

Caso tenha feito merge do `branch` no `master` é preciso que você reverta no master pra seguir os passos seguintes..

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Após isso pode fazer pull com segurança no master para ficar atualizado com o remote origin

```
git pull origin master
```

Então atualize o histórico dos commits no branch `mobile`

```
git rebase master mobile
```

se ocorrer conflito em qualquer commit deve fixar e executar `git rebase --continue`.
A Tree do `mobile` ficará como a seguir:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G -> master
             \     
              A-B-C -> mobile HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

No Github, você pode fazer um *Pull Request* da branch `mobile` para a branch `master`.

Após isto, esta solicitação de merge ficará disponível para ser avaliada. Se tudo estiver certo, é só entrar na solicitação de *pull request* e aprovar (fazer o *merge*) da mesma na master.

Se existirem conflitos, você tem duas opções:

1. Fazer o *merge* da branch `master` para a branch `mobile`, resolver os conflitos e fazer o `push` da resolução para a branch `mobile`. O Pull Request automaticamente detectará que o conflito foi resolvido e permitirá o merge.
2. Fazer o *merge* manualmente (sem usar *pull request*) da branch `mobile` para a branch `master`. A resolução do conflito se dará na própria branch `master`.